# Phonegap remote build don't add plugins

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

In our project we use Phonegap and we have added contacts plugin via phonegap-cli

phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts

When we build app locally its working fine. But when we use Phonegap online build its not add plugins to app. How we can configure our app to make online build install plugins in the app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify it inside the config.xml file

add

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" version="0.2.11" />
```

and the online build will work!

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/930